# Find a vector in the null space of a large dense matrix, where elements in the matrix are not directly accessible

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am working with Conjugate Gradient method to solve for $Ax = b$, where $A$ is an extremely large PSD and Singular matrix. I cannot directly access the elements of $A$, but I can compute $Av$ for any vector $v$.

Now, I would like to solve for $Ax = 0$, which is effectively finding one vector in the null space of $A$. I understand that it is slow to solve it with CG directly. I wonder if there are other iterative methods that would give a reasonably good solution with only the access of $Av$ very quickly?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: does this question have anything to do with the software Mathematica? If not it might be better at other Stack Exchange sites, and may risk closure

Comment: @Dunlop this question has a clear mathematical answer: use the [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration), as implemented in [ARPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK), to find the eigenvalue/vector with smallest magnitude. There is no mathematical difficulty here, it's all solved and well-known. Unfortunately, ARPACK's interface that only requires the black-box operation $\vec{v}\mapsto A\cdot\vec{v}$ is not exposed in Mathematica, and so the question becomes a particular difficulty in Mathematica.

Comment: @Roman that makes things clearer. It was just the question didnt seem as though it had anything to do with Mathematica

Comment: @Dunlop I am afraid you are correct. This answer is likely not related to Mathematica. I am new to the community and I apologise for my blunder. However, I would keep the question here since there seems to be some relevant information that could others in this community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm implementing a simplified version of the [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) with spectral shift here.

First, create a random 10✕10 PSD matrix that we'll use as an example:

```
n = 10;
A = Transpose[#] . # &@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}];
```

The eigenvalues of this matrix are all nonnegative (in your case, some will even be zero):

```
Eigenvalues[A] // Sort
(*    {0.0540622, 0.321272, 0.680714, 2.80777, 4.01219,
       10.5359, 12.1004, 17.871, 21.7634, 34.2863}         *)
```

Find the largest eigenvalue/vector by magnitude: a straight-forward Arnoldi iteration,

```
vmax = FixedPoint[Normalize[A . #] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n],
                  SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-12 &)]
(*    {-0.334135, 0.233949, 0.424574, -0.437277, 0.115131,
       0.376451, -0.0107379, 0.471395, 0.0544037, 0.286161}    *)
emax = (A . vmax) . vmax
(*    34.2863    *)
```

Now we use a "spectral shift" operation: we set the matrix $B=\lambda_{\text{max}}I-A$, whose largest eigenvalue is $\lambda_{\text{max}}-\lambda_{\text{min}}$. Therefore, finding the largest eigenvalue of $B$ allows us to find the smallest eigenvalue/vector of $A$ by magnitude:

```
vmin = FixedPoint[Normalize[emax # - A . #] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n],
                  SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-12 &)]
(*    {0.249744, -0.562473, 0.237567, -0.211816, 0.294718,
       -0.246993, -0.0820622, 0.0486029, -0.52359, 0.298061}    *)
emin = (A . vmin) . vmin
(*    0.0540622    *)
```

We see that `emin` and `emax` are the correct values (as calculated with `Eigenvalues[A]` above). We've found them iteratively, only requiring the operation $\vec{v}\mapsto A\cdot\vec{v}$ without ever looking at $A$ explicitly. You can replace every mention of `A . #` in the above code with a black-box function `Aop[#]`:

```
Aop[v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ]] := A . v

vmax = FixedPoint[Normalize[Aop[#]] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n],
                  SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-12 &)];
emax = Aop[vmax] . vmax;
vmin = FixedPoint[Normalize[emax # - Aop[#]] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, n],
                  SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-12 &)]
emin = Aop[vmin] . vmin

(*    {0.249744, -0.562473, 0.237567, -0.211816, 0.294718,
       -0.246993, -0.0820622, 0.0486029, -0.52359, 0.298061}    *)

(*    0.0540622    *)
```

If your matrix is singular, then the smallest eigenvalue `emin` will be zero; but this assumption is not made in the above code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, your solution seems to require access to eigenvalues of A, which is also inaccessible.

Comment: No it doesn't. I only calculated the eigenvalues to show that the iterative results are correct.

Comment: Oh I see. Essentially you compute emax with Arnoldi iteration, then use emax to find vmin. This is indeed a method that fits the question description. However, this method seems a little bit time-consuming when Av operation is expensive, correct?

Comment: It depends on the `SameTest` precision that you need. If a sloppy result is good enough, this method can be very fast. Also, if you have an *a priori* estimate of an upper bound of `emax`, then you can use that directly without calculating it by iteration.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on how to acquire an accurate priori estimate?

Comment: Additionally, I used CG to directly solve for Ax=0 and noticed that the convergence speed is much faster than the power iteration method (even if I directly give the method the true emax). Do you have any comments on the comparison of these methods? Hopfully I am not straying too far away from the initial question.

Comment: For an estimate of an upper bound of the largest eigenvalue, I'd suggest asking a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Provided that  A x can be calculated fast, you could try to minimize the norm of Ax where x is unit vector. E.g.:

For a test we create a singular matrix by:

```
n = 20;
m = DiagonalMatrix[Append[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n - 1], 0]];
mo = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]];
m = Transpose[mo] . m . mo;
Eigenvalues[m]
```

[image]

We now minimize Ax with Norm[x]==1:

vs = Array[Subscript[v, #] &, n];
sol = vs /. Minimize[{Norm[m . vs], Norm[vs] == 1}, vs][[2]]

To test if sol is in the Nullspace:

```
m . sol // Abs // Max
3.44922*10^-7
```